# InternalServerError (2228479) in Sinch VideoCalling

Tags: android, sinch, android-sinch-api

I have implemented sinch video calling, and here is my code.

```
@Override
public void onClientStarted(SinchClient sinchClient) {
    Log.e(TAG, "started");

    callClient = sinchClient.getCallClient();
    callClient.addCallClientListener(this);
}
public void initiateCall(String receiverId) {
    Call call = callClient.callUserVideo(receiverId);
    call.addCallListener(this);
}
```

But it always calling `onCallEnded()` and here is error i am getting in it

```
SessionDetails [startTime=1460378041, endTime=1460378049, progressTime=0, establishTime=0, terminationCause=FAILURE, 
                packetsSent=0, packetsReceived=0, error=SinchError[errorType=OTHER, 
                code=4000, message='InternalServerError (2228479)', 
                data={serverCode=2228479, serverMessage=InternalServerError}]]
```

Comment: can you share more of the logcat please

Comment: This is the only thing i am getting in onCallEnded().

Comment: If you implement onLogMessage you should get more stuff,

Comment: have you got solution of this?. I am getting same error while app to app voice calling

Comment: @DivyangPanchal not yet

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error it started coming since today only what I think its coming after I changed the notification settings only but its not, then I looked in more details, and I found the reason for me the problem is these two lines in my Localizable.strings file

```
SIN_INCOMING_VIDEO_CALL = "Incoming video call";
SIN_INCOMING_VIDEO_CALL_DISPLAY_NAME = "Incoming video call from %@";
```

So I just removed these two and every thing worked fine for me, although I am looking in it why these to text line created the problem,